# Is there a PPA for vim 7.3?

Tags: 10.04, ppa, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find Vim 7.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7283/where-can-i-find-vim-7-3)

Vim 7.3 is out, and there's a PPA for Ubuntu 10.10.

Is there a PPA for Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 2):

There's not a PPA unfortunately, but you could install [it from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7283/where-can-i-find-vim-7-3/7344#7344).

Answer (score 2):

Seems someone created a PPA ->

- [Where can I find Vim 7.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7283/where-can-i-find-vim-7-3)

Comment: this is not a duplicate question, and yes i saw that ppa. That ppa is for Ubuntu 10.10. I want vim 7.3 for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.