# How can I update vim to a newer version than 11.04's repo version (7.3.35)

Tags: 11.04, vim

Ubuntu 11.04 comes with vim 7.3.35 in the repos, and this version has a bug which is preventing me from using the Command-T plugin (the bug is http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=614336) which was apparently fixed in 7.3.154.

How can I update my local vim to at least this version? Do I have to completely uninstall and build from source or is there a PPA out there somewhere I can't find?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've blogged about this... It took me couple of hours so you may want to check it out [blog entrie](http://kresimirbojcic.com/2011/05/14/installing-command-t-ubunutu-11.04-ruby-1.9.2.html)

Kresimir Bojcic

[www.kresimirbojcic.com](http://www.kresimirbojcic.com)

Comment: Twitter link dead.

Comment: Can the content of this answer be updated? The link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly, can't find a more up-to-date PPA on Launchpad.  The 11.10 repositories have yet to be updated with a more recent version than in Natty.

You could uninstall VIM and compile the most recent source as per this AU answer: [Where can I find Vim 7.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7283/where-can-i-find-vim-7-3)

Alternatively you could try the Debian unstable packages here: http://packages.debian.org/sid/vim

Answer (score 3):

I found a ppa that updates vim on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92624/6445)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:blueyed/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/blueyed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: @Von: The package exists; try again or check your sources.

Answer (score 1):

egarcia's answer helped me install a newer version of vim, which I appreciate, but I still had a problem.  A plugin I wanted to install required vim 7.3.584+, which wasn't available via that PPA.

For those in the same boat as I was, I found [this guide](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) for installing higher versions of vim by compiling vim from source.  As the guide says, don't worry, it's easy.

(Aside, that plugin is the reason I wanted a newer version of vim.  It's fantastic autocomplete)